# List comprehension works but not generator expression

Tags: python, list-comprehension, generator-expression

I am doing this problem:

> Given an array of integers arr, a lucky integer is an integer which has a frequency in the array equal to its value.
> Return a lucky integer in the array. If there are multiple lucky integers return the largest of them. If there is no lucky integer return -1.

I am using this code, which works and passed all tests:

```py
class Solution:
    def findLucky(self, arr: List[int]) -> int:
        values = [n for n in arr if n if arr.count(n) == n]
        return max(values) if values else -1
```

However, when I try to change the list comprehension to a generator expression like so:

```py
class Solution:
    def findLucky(self, arr: List[int]) -> int:
        values = (n for n in arr if n if arr.count(n) == n)
        return max(values) if values else -1
```

I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "...", line 10, in <module>
    print(Solution().findLucky([2, 3, 4]))
  File "...", line 7, in findLucky
    return max(values) if values else -1
ValueError: max() arg is an empty sequence
```

Why does a list comprehension work whereas a generator expression fails?

I've tried converting the generator expression to a list in the comprehension, but that won't work because then the generator is exhuased.

Comment: A generator is *always* truthy, whether or not it will ever produce any values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every generator is true, so you always call `max(values)` even if the generator is "empty". The right way to do it is to tell `max` what to do then:

```
return max(values, default=-1)
```

Comment: It's even  a stretch to talk about a generator being "empty", as they aren't containers. They are *producers*, and the only way to tell if a generator will produce a value is to try to retrieve it via the iterator protocol.

Comment: @chepner Alright, put it in quotes, hopefully that's clear enough :-)